# Kendo grid export to excel header title shows html characters

Tags: angularjs, excel, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

When I export my grid to excel,headers are like: **Product Name**,`{{'unitsOrder'| translate}}` in excel. My grid supports 2 languages and I am showing it with angularjs translate way. Any offer?

```
 <script>
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        toolbar: ["excel"],
        excel: {
            fileName: "Kendo UI Grid Export.xlsx"
        },
        dataSource: {
            type: "odata",
            transport: {
                read: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Products"
            },
            pageSize: 7
        },
        sortable: true,
        pageable: true,
        columns: [
            { width: 300, field: "ProductName", title: "<b>Product Name</b>" },
            { field: "UnitsOnOrder", title: "{{'unitsOrder'| translate}}" },
            { field: "UnitsInStock", title: "Units In Stock" }
        ]
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but I use i18next translation instead of angular but maybe it helps you find a solution to your case:

I use the 'excelExport' event to manually update the generated worksheet. Within the worksheet object I search for the header cells and manually trigger the translation for the text it contains:

```
 excelExport: function(e) {

        // First I loop through all rows in the worksheet
        e.workbook.sheets[0].rows.forEach(function(row){

          // Ignore 'data' rows (only use 'header' and 'footer')
          if(row.type != 'data'){

            // Loop through all cells of the row
            row.cells.forEach(function(cell){

              // Here I overwrite the cell value with its translation
              // You have to implement translate() so it works with angular
              cell.value = translate(cell.value)
            });
          }
        });
      },
```

You now have to write your own translate function which can handle your angular translation. As I use i18next for translations my solution won't help here (I use jquery to generate a jquery html object on which I can trigger the translation)